# Can we merge [efi] and [uefi] tags please?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Many moons ago, I asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207913/can-we-merge-efi-and-uefi-tags-please) on the old meta (now meta.stackexchange.com) to see if anyone could find it in their heart to merge the [uefi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uefi) and [efi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efi) tags. Though there wasn't really any disagreement, nothing happened at the time.

I've now put up a [synonym suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/uefi/synonyms) up, but since this tag is rarely visited I thought I would solicit some votes, or more direct action, here.

As a back story - [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) is the  name of the specification that was created when Intel transferred ownership of version 1.10 of the EFI specification to the [UEFI Forum](http://www.uefi.org/) in 2005.

Comment: Nobody has sufficient rep in the [efi] tag to upvote your synonym suggestion.  I think you need the assistance of a moderator.  And yes, it is appropriate.

Comment: Would there be any benefits in retaining both to distinguish between the two (for some reason)? I'm not against the idea - but it's not a field I can completely say yay/nay on - so it has to to come down to community consensus... (which is admittedly difficult given the rarity of the tags). I appreciate @Hans' input - hasn't quite pushed the opinion enough to push it through though...

Comment: @JonClements: not really. Pretty much all of the (few) on-topic questions tagged EFI are actually about UEFI. And even if that wasn't the case, UEFI can pretty much be considered a superset of the old Intel-internal-only specification.

Comment: @unixsmurf So basically this is like if C was deprecated and C++ was used everywhere instead, and one asked to merge C and C++ tags because most `[C]` questions were actually related to C++ and only few were about actual C. (I hope this makes sense)

Comment: @VladislavToncharov well, it's slightly weirder. First of all, EFI was never a public specification, and resulting firmware was never developed in the open (although some applications running under it was). Given that the transition to UEFI (and public development) predates Stackoverflow, it's more like someone created a 'Solaris' tag when they actually meant 'Opensolaris'.